# Difference in syntax of a normal dictionary and OrderedDictonary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

The syntax of printing a normal dictionary is

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Whereas

The syntax of printing a OrderedDict is

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

Is there any way where i can print/return the OrderedDict in the Normal Dictionary way??

Comment: But my question is why do you want to do that? Printing the dict as it is something which is never required. In order to fetch content from it, you may do it like normal dict

Comment: I have a test program which runs my program and checks for my output with a previously defined output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The easy way:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
new_dict = dict(OrderedDict(a))
print(new_dict)
print(type(new_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
<type 'dict'>
```

**The hard way:**

You can also return the OrderedDict to a simple dict using `groupby` from `itertools` module like this way:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby
a = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

new_dict = {key:list(val)[0][1] for key, val in groupby(OrderedDict(a).items(), lambda x : x[0])}
print(new_dict)
print(type(new_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2`}
<type 'dict'>
```

**Edit:**

I see that there is some downvotes because they think that the output should be an ordered string. So, this is how do deal with it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
new_dict = OrderedDict(a)

b = "{%s}" % ", ".join([str(key)+":"+str(val) for key, val in sorted(new_dict.iteritems())])

print(b)
print(type(b))
```

Output:

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Both solutions here do not print items in the ordered dict order... In fact this is just converting an ordered dict to a dict, whereas the question was about getting an ordered string representation of the ordered dict like if it was a normal dict... Well, maybe the question is not clear

Comment: @mguijarr This is why i added the type `<type 'dict'>`. And like you know there is not any specific order in a dict type. Also, the OP want to have a dict type from OrderedDict type and the OP didn't said he want a string output but `in the Normal Dictionary way` and this mean a simple `dict` type not a string or other. Also, this is why he accepted my answer too. So downvoting me, isn't a good attitude. Otherwise, you're welcome.

Comment: I removed my down vote... Although I still find your answer does not correspond entirely to the question. But as it seems the OP is happy with it, it's probably me who didn't understand.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom `__str__` method in your own `OrderedDict` class ; in the custom method, you can build the string you want:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
   def __str__(self):
      return "{%s}" % ", ".join([repr(k)+": "+str(v) for k, v in self.iteritems()])

d = MyOrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

Comment: But, the return of `d.__str__()` is a string not a dict.

Comment: @nexus66 I should hope so, since `__str__` is supposed to return a string, not a dict.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes indeed. But the OP said he want the OrderedDict in the Normal Dictionary way.

Comment: @nexus66 Well, they wanted to print in that form, which just requires returning a string.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right and maybe 'Normal Dictionary way" confuses me. Thanks by the way @SethMMorton.

Answer (score 0):

To print `OrderedDict` in a `dict`-way you can act like this (of course, if the actual order of the items does not matter to print):

```
def some_function():
    d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
    od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
    return od

my_ordered_dict_variable = some_function()
print('My Ordered Dicdict:', dict(my_ordered_dict_variable))
```

This code will print:

```
{'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
```